# HLSL multiple passes to blur (RTT?)

Tags: hlsl, render-to-texture

I try to build up a complex water shader ( i got the water shader from an example in the internet ).
Now i want to add some features, blend a pattern grid into the water which is blured.
Atm the water and the blur works, but when i try to build up the blur effekt with some randomization ... i use to many instruction for the shader ... :(

I searched for topics like "hlsl multiple passes", "hlsl render to texture", "hlsl multiple passes without texture", cause i dont have an existing "ground" texture.

I build up the water from a normal map and a enviroment map, now ... is it possible to get this "whole map / texture / shader data" from the first pass into the second ?
Cause when i only execute the both passes, the color from the first pass get completely overwritten :(

I hope you guys can understand my problem and have all the information you need.

Would be nice if you would help me.

Thanks...

Comment: What shader model do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try compiling for shader model 3.0. It allows to use more instructions.

If you want to perform multiple passes you don't have to use rendering to target. You should enable alpha blending to prevent previous colors from being overwritten.

However, this will not work if you need to sample the output of the previous pass. In this case you need 2 textures (A and B, both created as render targets). Follow these steps:

1. Set render target to texture A.
2. Render the first pass.
3. Set render target to texture B (or to the final render target, if you don't need to sample texture B in the following render process).
4. Set up hlsl sampler with texture A (using ID3DXEffect::SetTexture, for example).
5. Render the second pass (using texture A for sampling).

If you have more than 2 passes, swap A and B and do steps 3.-5. for each pass.

Comment: hey hey,
thnaks for your answer, i will try to build it up but atm it looks like that i will need some time to rly understand it ( more or less new at shader programming )
btw ... my "IDE" atm is nividia fx composer 2.5
and atm didnt find anything to get fx to render to a render target ...

but i keep trying :) 
maybe you have some advise for the fx composer :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience in using fx composer. Anyway, you should set up render targets with Direct3D because there's no option to change render target in effect file (.fx).

Comment: uhh, ... thanks man.... this saved me some research time :)
then i will try your anwser next time :)

Comment: its a bit embaressing but :)
with this states i got it to work in the fx composer
  `AlphaBlendEnable = True;
  SrcBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
  DestBlend = SrcAlpha;`

and in the xna game project it works too ... ( no need for RTT )
but, is got some other errors in the xna project -.-
when i try to "blur several times" i get the ID3DXEffectCompiler: Compilation failed error....
i know its the wrong topic for this but maybe you have any sugestions :)

`float4 Color =tex2D(s2,  vTexCoord); 
Color +=tex2D(s2,vTexCoord.xy + 0.0075F);
Color +=tex2D(s2,vTexCoord.xy + 0.005F);
 and this multiple times

Comment: dnt know at all what specefic error number it is ...
but when i try to run the xna game via visual studio 
the error log only say something like:
`ID3DXEffectCompiler: Compilation failed`
and vs points me to: `PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS_Water_BlurV();`

sry ... i dnt have much experience with shading :)

Comment: When you compile an effect with `ID3DXEffectCompiler`, you can get the error message (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205790(v=vs.85).aspx - use `ppErrorMsgs` parameter) and for example print it into some file. If you couldn't find the bug yourself, edit your question and paste the code of your shader.